# Decode cp1252 stdout with umlauts

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.4

I want to list the services running on the local Windows machine. For that, I am using this code:

```
with Popen(["net", "start"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()  # type: (bytes, bytes)
```

A part of the output looks like this (German Windows version):

```
Folgende Windows-Dienste sind gestartet:

   Anmeldedienst
   [...]
   Benachrichtigungsdienst für Systemereignisse
```

Decoding the bytes to a string should be easy. I checked the documentation and found the local encoding on the command line:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'cp1252'
```

Therefore, I would like to decode the bytes:

```
lines = stdout.decode('cp1252')
```

However, for the umlaut `ü` listed in the example, I get an error message:

```
File "test.py", line 511, in my_func
    lines = stdout.decode('cp1252')
File "C:\Python344\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 152: character maps to <undefined>
```

However, I know that [UTF-8 contains a representation of the `ü` character](https://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/):

```
U+00FC  ü   c3 bc   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
```

I am at a loss why this translation cannot be done.

Notes:

- I know when using `universal_newslines=True` for the `Popen` call, I can circumvent the whole ordeal, but using that was what lead me to analyse what the problem with the encoding is.
- Starting with Python 3.5, it seems that the `Popen` constructor got an `encoding=` option added, maybe this would prevent questions like this. Sadly, Python 3.4 is the version included in certain LTS Linux versions.

Edit 1: Something is afoot here. Although the Python 3.4 documentation states that the default encoding is cp1252 on Windows, when running the command on the CLI and redirecting to a file, the file is encoded in IBM850. Best guess would be that the `locale.getpreferredencoding()` doesn't return the encoding of the CLI.

Edit 2: A decoding of the stdout using `ibm850` works like a charm. That means that using `universal_newlines=True` for the `Popen` call does use the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, however, that is the wrong encoding to decode the CLI output.

Comment: You aren't running `net` via the CLI; you are executing it directly from your Python process. That may be making a difference in how `net` decides what encoding to use.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you use something like `Popen("net start", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is:

When using a `Popen` call with `universal_newslines=True`, that forces a string interpretation of the returned stdout, stderr data. However, the interpretation is done using the encoding that is returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, which in this case was `cp1252`. However, the data on the command line was not encoded using `cp1252` (Windows-like ANSI style encoding), but `ibm850` (DOS encoding). Because decoding operated on bytes and int, and because the int in the stdout for `ü` (0x81) had no corresponding value in the `cp1252` decoding table, an exception from the depths of Python was thrown.

Decoding the command line data manually with `str.decode('ibm850')` decoded correctly.

Note: Starting with Python 3.5, `Popen` allows the passing of an encoding to be used for the data flow, which Python 3.4 lacks.